# Как сделать пагинацию страниц по 5 отзывов на странице?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, pagination

Как сделать чтобы после 5 отзывов нужно было переключать на вторую страницу и так далее, то-бишь переключатель страниц?
Создал таблицу (вот моя таблица)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в корень папки создал файл db.php
Вот его содержимое (* - заменил пароль)

```
<?php 
$dblocation = '*******'; // имя хоста
$database = '*******'; // имя базы данных 
$dbuser = '*******'; // имя пользователя
$dbpasswd = '************'; // пароль пользователя

// устанавливаем соединение с базой данных 

$link = mysqli_connect($dblocation, $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $database) or die("Не могу подключиться");  
mysqli_select_db($link, $database) or die ('Не могу выбрать БД');

//установка кодировки
$link->set_charset("utf8");
?>
```

Далее создал файл формы form.php

```
<?php include_once 'db.php'; ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Отзывы о продукте</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>

 <?php $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `Otzivy2` ORDER BY id DESC") ?> 
 <?php while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>

<div class="reviews">
  
<div class="review_text">
<b>Имя:</b> <?= $res['name'] ?> | <b>Дата:</b> <?= date("d.m.y | <b>Время:</b> H.i", strtotime($res['date'])) ?> | <b>Оценка:</b> <?= $res['rating'] ?>/5
<hr>
<br>
<?= $res['message'] ?> <br>
</div>
</div>

<?php } ?>

<div class="content">
<h2>Отзыв о продукте</h2>
<h3>Все поля обязательны для заполнения</h3>
<br>
<div class="send"> 
<form method="post" action="index.php" id="review">   
<h3>Оцените продукт</h3>
<div class="rating">
<input type="radio" class="rating" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5"></label>
<input type="radio" class="rating" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4"></label>
<input type="radio" class="rating" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3"></label>
<input type="radio" class="rating" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2"></label>
<input type="radio" class="rating" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star1"></label>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Ваш E-mail" required>
<input type="date" name="date" hidden="true">
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Сообщение" required></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Оставить отзыв">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Затем в файл index.php добавил вот этот код

```
<?
include_once 'db.php';

if (isset($_POST['add'])) {

// преобразуем специальные символы в текст

$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
$rating = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rating']);

// заносим данные из формы в переменные и проверяем на ошибки

$name = strip_tags(trim($_POST['name']));
$email = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']));
$message = strip_tags(trim($_POST['message']));
$rating = strip_tags(trim($_POST['rating']));
$date = $_POST['date'];

// заносим дату и время отзыва
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i');

// проверка введенных данных

if($name != '' AND $email != '' AND $message != ''){ if (!preg_match("/[0-9a-z_]+@[0-9a-z_^\.]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/i", $email)) {$err = 'Неверно введен е-mail.';}

// отправка данных в бд

mysqli_query($link, " INSERT INTO otzivi (name, email, message, date, rating) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$message', '$date', '$rating')");

// закрываем сеанс 

mysqli_close($link);

//редирект

header ("location: index.php");
   }
}

include_once 'form.php';
?>
```

Comment: советую не начинать учить `php` в 2020 году. Он уже по популярности катится в низ. Так, чисто совет

Comment: Экспертные мнения подъехали, лол

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код прошёл проверку.

```
<?php 

$num = 5; // Количество отзывов

if ($_GET['page'] == NULL) $page = 1; //Если страница не определена - опреелить
else $page = $_GET['page']; 

$start = $page * $num - $num; // Подсчёт строки

/* Получаем данные */
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *  FROM otzivi ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT " . $start . "," . $num);
/*******************/

/* Проверяем наличие другой страницы */
$start = $start + $num;
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM otzivi ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT " . $start . "," . $num);
$check = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if ($check <= 0) $load = ''; // Если страницы нет - скрыть
else $load = '<a href="?page='. ++$page .'">Next</a>';
echo $load;
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо. В какой файл надо добавить этот код?

Comment: В самый низ index.php

Comment: жауется на эту часть кода else $load = '<a href="?page='.$page+1.'">Next</a>';

Comment: хм, попробуйте разделить математическое выражение
`else $load = '<a href="?page='. $page+1 .'">Next</a>';`

Comment: или использовать так `else $load = '<a href="?page='. ++$page .'">Next</a>';`

Comment: почему-то не появилась пагинация

Comment: сделайте вывод... `echo $load;`

Comment: не изменилось ничего (

Comment: Какое количество строк в БД?

Comment: их может быть сколько угодно, люди  же отзывы будут оставлять

Comment: сейчас их больше 5?

Comment: Да, в таблице больше 5

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116972/discussion-between--and-arcadiy).